# Crystal Reports 2011: Formula works after I create a new exact formula

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2011

has anyone come across this issue where a formula would not work for unknown reason but if i cut it out. Save this formula and then paste it back in it would now work again?
formula is basically below. Its meant to total up a number. It seems to not evaluate the IF statement correctly and put through a 0 all the time. But once i cut that formula out and paste it back in it would add in whatever {@LYMAT_combined} value is.

```
whileprintingrecords;
shared numberVar LYMAT_Comp;
LYMAT_Comp := LYMAT_Comp + if {@Combo_Sales} < 24 then 0 else {@LYMAT_combined};
```

Also this is my Calc_All formula which is sitting in the a group footer and basically does the above similar formula for multiple totals which i call for in another group footer which display the totals. Calc_All is fairly big is there a set number of lines of formula u can add to a formula field? ive declared around 50 shared variables and formula within it.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

For one, you don't need to use `Shared` scope--it's only for sharing a value between a main report and its subreports.  Use `Global` instead.

In you situation, it's better to use a formula field:

```
// {@LYMAT_Comp}
if {@Combo_Sales} < 24 then 0 
else {@LYMAT_combined}
```

Then summarize the formula field (Insert | Summary...)

Comment: Hi craig i declared them as a variable as i needed the figure to be stored in LYMAT_Comp variable and then i need to call up and display this figure in the group footer where all the totals will be displayed which is why i have used shared scope. I tried changing it to global and calling the figures back out but it doesnt seem to work so i have changed it back to shared again. Thanks for taking the time to answer my question

Comment: Just wondering does anyone know if there is a limit on how big a Formula field can be? the Calc_All formula is basically an area where i have been storing all my manual running total calculations for my 3 Formula trick. I have declared probably over 60 variables and including around 50 manual running total formula's.

Comment: You can easily copy the summarized field and place it in a group's header or footer.  Moreover, you can also use it in the report's footer section (a grand total).  Don't make extra work for yourself.

I don't know if there is a limit to the # of variables.  I try to avoid using manual running totals if at all possible...

Comment: hi craig. Worked out what the issue was. I was just randomly adding formula's to the calc_all formula field as i was creating new formulas. But when i cleaned it up and made it sequential as in when the report would call up the first formula to last, top down approach, everything seems to calculate properly now. Ive reconciled a few of the reports and it looks good hopefully this would be the end of this issue

Answer (score 0):

you can do as many things you want to do in a formula, there is no limit, but make sure that the output is one, multiple outputs may result in error.